# Disjoint union of sets enumerating possible coin collections

Tags: combinatorics

> There is a bag containing 10 nickels, 20 dimes, and 30 quarters.  You
>   are allowed to reach in the bag and grab a collection  of  coins.
>   (Note  that  coins  of  the  same  denomination  are  considered  to 
>   be  the  same,  so  we  are  mainly interested in the number of coins
>   of each denomination.)
>
> a) Write a set (as a Cartesian product) which enumerates all possible  collections where there is at least one coin of each denomination.
>
> b) Write a disjoint union of sets which enumerates all possible
>   collections where there is at least one coin of each denomination, and
>   there are more nickels than quarters.

I have solved part (a) with
$\mathbb{S}=\{1,...,10\}\times\{1,...,20\}\times\{1,...,30\}$ representing all possible combinations of nickels, dimes, and quarters, respectively.

How can I begin part (b)? I have tried $\mathbb{S}=\{2\}\times\{1,...,20\}\times\{1\}\ \cup \ \{3\} \times \{1,...20\} \times \{1,2\}\ \cup \ ...\ \cup \ \{10\} \times \{1,...,20\}\times\{1,...,9\}$

However this doesn't really make any sense to me. Any help would be appreciated. If you need anything else, let me know.